# Eliminate duplicates within a range then move the non-blank cells to top of same range, without shifting cells outside the range

Tags: excel, vba

The [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxFNr.png) image represents educational background that an employee has reported. As you can see, the report that produces the info creates unwanted duplicates and spaces. Can't do anything about that. The [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/py3tr.png) image shows my desired end result. To get there, I manually:

1. Deleted the duplicates
2. Copy/pasted the remaining occupied cells to the top of the range **without shifting** any cells below the range. (Yes, there is data below the range).

How do I automate this with VBA? The [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxFNr.png) image represents the range F3:H18 and I've named the range **edVal**.

This range will always be 3 columns (F-H). The number of rows will vary but I already have code that selects edVal, no matter how many rows it may be.

I have other code doing other stuff elsewhere in the sheet but then I come to this education portion. Assume I've dim'd edVal as Range and edVal is selected. Seems the additional code I need will fit between "With edVal" and End With.

Comment: Please show the code you've tried thusfar.  StackOverflow is a collaborative site dedicated to helping with *specific* coding issues; it is not a code-for-you site.  If you need help getting started, use the Macro Recorder under the Developer tab in Excel.  For specific things to google, try .ClearContents and .Sort

Comment: Shown below as user9335726. Somehow accidentally created a second profile. Awaiting feedback from site to merge.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like below, it will remove duplicates and loop through F3 to F18 and if it finds a blank row, it will delete and shift up, but then it will insert a blank row at the bottom, thus leaving your data below the range intact.

Simply adjust the code below with your value from edVal:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

ws.Range("$F$3:$H$18").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlNo

For i = 3 To 18
If ws.Cells(i, "F").Value = "" Then
    ws.Range("F" & i & ":H" & i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ws.Range("F18:H18").Insert Shift:=xlDown
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the values for edVal worked as suggested. That code is between the "With edVal / End With" lines. Also shown, is the code I already had.

```
Sub foo()
Dim empRange as Range, edVal as Range
Dim f as Integer, l as Integer

Set empRange = Range("A3:Z18")   'rows 1 and 2 are headers
  With empRange
    f = empRange.Row
    l = empRange.Rows.Count
    Set edVal = Range(.Cells(, 6), .Cells(l, 8))  'edVal is columns F-H of the larger empRange
    With edVal
      .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), HEADER:=xlNo
      For i = f To l + 2     'adding 2 to account for two header rows
        If Range("F" & i).Value = "" Then
          Range("F" & i & ":" & "H" & i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
          Range("F" & l + 2 & ":" & "H" & l + 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
      Next I
    End With
  End With                    
End Sub
```